# Underscore followed by numbers instead of solution

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to solve a version of Einstein's Riddle. Therefore I defined a few rules:

```
students(Students) :-
    length(Students, 6),
    member([manuel, _, _, _], Students),
    member([tobias, _, pas, _], Students),
    member([louise, _, _, _], Students),
    member([sophia, _, _, _], Students),
    member([hannes, 18, _, _], Students),
    member([oliver, _, _, _], Students),
    member([_, 18, _, _], Students),
    member([_, 19, _, win], Students),
    member([_, 20, stu, _], Students),
    member([_, 21, _, _], Students),
    member([_, 22, _, _], Students),
    member([_, 23, _, _], Students),
    member([_, _, ulm, _], Students),
    member([_, _, fra, _], Students),
    member([_, _, pas, _], Students),
    member([_, _, hei, inf], Students),
    member([_, _, aug, _], Students),
    member([_, _, stu, _], Students),
    member([_, _, _, win], Students),
    member([_, _, _, wig], Students),
    member([_, _, _, bwl], Students),
    member([_, _, _, inf], Students),
    member([_, _, _, gbm], Students),
    member([_, _, _, rwi], Students).
```

As I tested it to see if there are any error so far, I encountered the following output:

```
?- students(X).
X = [[manuel, 19, ulm, win], [tobias, 21, pas, _1574], [louise, 20, stu, _1604], [sophia, 22, fra, _1634], [hannes, 18, hei, inf], [oliver, 23, aug, _1694]]
X = [[manuel, 19, ulm, win], [tobias, 21, pas, _1350], [louise, 20, stu, _1380], [sophia, 22, fra, _1410], [hannes, 18, hei, inf], [oliver, 23, aug, _1470]]
X = [[manuel, 19, ulm, win], [tobias, 21, pas, _1350], [louise, 20, stu, _1380], [sophia, 22, fra, _1410], [hannes, 18, hei, inf], [oliver, 23, aug, _1470]]
X = [[manuel, 19, ulm, win], [tobias, 21, pas, _1350], [louise, 20, stu, _1380], [sophia, 22, fra, _1410], [hannes, 18, hei, inf], [oliver, 23, aug, _1470]]
...
```

Since there are more rules needed to solve it completely I was expecting more than one solution. But I'm confused why `win` and `inf` are used correctly but `wig`, `bwl`, `rwi` and `gbm` are not.

Could you explain to me why this happens and how to fix it?

*(I don't know if it's just a problem of the dialect. Thus, I tested it on the website https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/examples.swinb)*

Comment: You do not specify the "domain" of the items. So all elements can be *free* variables.

Comment: Note: "Sutdents" vs "Students"

Comment: @jnmonette thanks, I corrected that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the domains for the values. As a result all variables can, to some extent, remain free. You can make use of [**`permutation/2`**](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2) for example to specify that the names are limited to `manuel`, `tobias`, `louise`, `sophia`, `hannes`, and `oliver`:

```
students(Students) :-
    Students = [
        [manuel, AA, SA, TA],
        [tobias, AB, SB, TB],
        [louise, AC, SC, TC],
        [sophia, AD, SD, TD],
        [hannes, AE, SE, TE],
        [oliver, AF, SF, TF]
    ],
    member([tobias, _, pas, _], Students),
    member([hannes, 18, _, _], Students),
    member([_, 19, _, win], Students),
    member([_, 20, stu, _], Students),
    member([_, _, hei, inf], Students),
    permutation([AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]),
    permutation([SA, SB, SC, SD, SE, SF], [ulm, fra, pas, hei, aug, stu]),
    permutation([TA, TB, TC, TD, TE, TF], [win, wig, bwl, inf, gbm, rwi]).
```

We here can set the order of the names already fixed, since there are *no* predicates like "*Manuel is located next to a person with age 20*", this is thus a form of symmetry we can remove (or you can use `permutation/2` if necessary).

We furthermore do not have to mention any constraints that only restrict domains. We can do that with `member/2`, but it would likely be less efficient, and furthermore then we have to *fully* specify the domain, not only cases like `member([hannes, 18, _, _], Students)`, since this makes a connection between hannes who is 18 years old.

This gives us 44'928 solutions, if we allow an arbitrary order of students, we have to multiply this with 4! = 24, so then there are 1'078'272 solutions.